# Mapeamento de URL

Tags: java, servlet

Ao acessar o perfil de algum usuário, passo o nome do usuário dele como um parâmetro.

```
www.site.com.br/busca?usuario=nomedousuario
```

gostaria de acessar da seguinte maneira

```
www.site.com.br/nomedousuario
```

alguém tem a luz do fim do tunel pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um filtro de Servlet (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), que vai pegar a requisição http, interpretar e converter em uma nova url.
A instalação é simples, é só adicionar o arquivo urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar no WEB-INF/lib. No web.xml você adiciona o seguinte:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Sugiro que dê uma lida na documentação deles também.

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade @Jonathan, seria interessante fazer uma compilação da matéria e colocar aqui, pois se o link sair do ar não vai ter mais a solução aqui.

Comment: Obrigado marco, irei fazê-lo

Comment: E o arquivo de configura, `urlrewrite.xml`, não precisa? Como será o padrão de reescrita da URL só com o filtro?